# Data em um gráfico Highstock

Tags: php, javascript, data, highcharts, timestamp

Estou tentando criar um gráfico com o framework [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/), para criar um gráfico, que o próprio framewor disponibiliza, [highstock](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo).

Estou tetando gerar um gráfico do tipo linha, os valores estão corretos, porem a data fica errada. Olhei em um [arquivo](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?) do framework onde, nos exemplos que eles demonstram, buscam os dados.

Uma parte do trecho:

```
[
[1285718400000,41.05],
[1285804800000,40.54],
/* Oct 2010 */
[1285891200000,40.36],
[1286150400000,39.81],
[1286236800000,41.28],
[1286323200000,41.31],
[1286409600000,41.32],
[1286496000000,42.01],
[1286755200000,42.19],
[1286841600000,42.65],
[1286928000000,42.88],
[1287014400000,43.19],
[1287100800000,44.96],
[1287360000000,45.43],
[1287446400000,44.21],
[1287532800000,44.36],
[1287619200000,44.22],
[1287705600000,43.92],
[1287964800000,44.12],
[1288051200000,44.01],
[1288137600000,43.98],
[1288224000000,43.61],
[1288310400000,43.00],
/* Nov 2010 */
[1288569600000,43.45],
[1288656000000,44.19],
[1288742400000,44.69],
[1288828800000,45.47],
[1288915200000,45.30],
[1289174400000,45.52],
```

Logo percebi que os valores da esquerda, com 13 caracteres, poderiam ser as data.

No meu código eu fiz desta maneira:

**Observação:** Os dois trechos de código estão no mesmo arquivo.

PHP:

```
$valorTendencia[] = array(strtotime($value->DataHoraPrevisao),$value->Valor);
$encodeValorTendencia = json_encode($valorTendencia, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: <?php echo $encodeValorTendencia; ?>
        },{
            name: 'Teste',
            data: <?php echo $encodeValorObtencao; ?>
        }]
    });
</script>
```

Mas pega uma data de 1970, e as datas que eu quero são atuais.

Na variável `$value->DataHoraPrevisao` está as datas que quero utilizar e estão neste formato: (string) `2017-09-01 03:00:00`.

Na [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock) não consegui encontrar nada relacionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver concatenando uma string na frente do `strtotime($value->DataHoraPrevisao)`, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
$valorTendencia[] = array(strtotime($value->DataHoraPrevisao)."000",$value->Valor);
$encodeValorTendencia = json_encode($valorTendencia, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```